# How can I append spearman Rho stat to new object?

Tags: r, lapply

I am carrying out a number of spearman's rank correlations and I want to produce a list of all the Rho estimates automatically.

Here is some sample data:

```
A <- data.frame('Area' = c(4, 6, 5),
                'flow' = c(1, 1, 1))
B <- data.frame('Area' = c(6, 8, 4),
                'flow' = c(1, 2, 1))
files <- list(A, B)
frames <- list('A', 'B')
```

I currently have the following code that carries out a correlation for each data frame in the list:

```
lapply(files, function (x)
    cor.test(~flow + Area, data = x, method = 'spearman'))
```

However, what I would like to do is add another line to this to extract the Rho estimation for each correlation and append this to a new list.

How can I do this?

Comment: Simply extract the estimate in call: `cor.test(...)$estimate`?

Comment: Oh wow, it was actually that simple. Thanks!